# Xamarin.Forms (iOS 14.1) Observables against NSUserDefaults using a key with dots don't get triggered

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

This code works (the observable gets called)

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.AddObserver(this, "sectionname_mykey", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("test", "sectionname_mykey");
```

But this one doesn't

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.AddObserver(this, "sectionname.mykey", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString("test", "sectionname.mykey");
```

The tooltip for the keyPath reads "Key-path to use to perform the value lookup. The keypath consists of a series of lowercase ASCII-strings with no spaces in them separated by dot characters" but the observables don't get called if I add a dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `NSObject` does not support using this way to set a key in iOS, and the inner error will show something like the following:

> Foundation.MonoTouchException: 'Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<IOSSplashScreen_Item 0x600002fc1510> addObserver:<ViewController 0x7fa6f35204b0> forKeyPath:@"sectionname.mykey" options:1 context:0x0] was sent to an object that is not KVC-compliant for the "sectionname" property.

If you need to an observer for an attribute of `sectionname`, you can use the following code:

```
// Sectionname should be a NSobject object and have observer notification 
Sectionname sectionname = new sectionname();
sectionname.AddObserver(this, "smykey", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: ohhh that makes perfect sense! I was reading the tooltip as if it were to tell me the naming convention for the keys, and it is in fact telling me "this is not just a string, it is the path that will be used to find the value you want to observe". That was completely my bad.